# How to change limit of messages when i scroll to top?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a chat with total of 20 messages displayed, and i want to make when user scroll to top to change that value from 20 to 30 and to update the chat. So, it is one time scroll, you scroll one time to top and you get in total 30 messages instead of 20. Here is what i have so far:

So this is global/default value:

`let limit = 20;`

This is how i print messages:

```
function print_msg() {

        var output = [];
        // console.log(limit);
        console.log('messages:', messages);
        for(var i=0; i<limit && i<messages.length; i++){ // here is where i use that limit
            var msg = messages[i];

            output.push(
                `
                <div class="row chat-strip">
                    // chat messages
                </div>
                
                `);
        }
        $("#chat-ul").html(output.reverse().join(''));
    }
```

Here i have scroll detector that i fixed position to -492 because when i have default 20 messages, my scrollbar will be at -492 position when i scroll to top and it's working.

```
    const chatContainer = $('#chatbox');
    chatContainer.scroll(function() {
        if(chatContainer[0].scrollTop === -492 && !isLoading){
            isLoading = true;
            limit = 30;
            print_msg();
        }
    });
```

As you can see it has `limit = 30;` that's the new limit when i scroll to top and function `print_msg();` to load the chat.

This is how i get data:

```
    function loadOrSend(q, data) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../includes/data/chat.php",
            data: {q: q, data: data, limit: limit},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(retr){
                if( q == 'load' ){
                    console.log(limit);
                    curr_id = retr.id;
                    messages = [...retr.data, ...messages];
                    if( retr.data.length > 0 ){
                        print_msg();
                    }
                    isLoading = false;
                }
                if( q == 'send' ){
                    playSound();
                }
            },
        }).fail(function () {
            alert("error: chat can't be loaded!");
        });
    }
setInterval(() => loadOrSend('load', curr_id), 3000);
```

I put `console.log` there and it is showing the limit of 30, but just need to make that limit go to `print_msg();` i guess.

And this is DB and all the stuff where it gets everything:

```
$q = $_POST["q"];
        $data = $_POST["data"];
        $retr = ["data"=>array(), "id"=>0];
        $limit = $_POST['limit'];

        if($q == "load") {
            $load = DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM chat WHERE id > $data ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit");
            if($load->count()){
                $retr["data"] = $load->results();
                $retr["id"]   = max(array_column($retr["data"], 'id')); // get the last chat id
            }else{
                $retr["data"] = array();
                $retr["id"]   = $data;
            }
        } elseif ($q == "send") {
            $insert = DB::getInstance()->insert('chat', array(
                'text' => parseSmiley(badWords(escape(preg_replace( '/(http|ftp)+(s)?:(\/\/)((\w|\.)+)(\/)?(\S+)?/i', '', showBBcodes(trim($data)))))),
                'username' => escape($user->data()->username),
                'avatar' => escape($user->getAvatar())
            ));
        }

        echo json_encode($retr);
```

I hope you guys can help me because i feel like im really close...